# Reorder the whole MySQL table based on column values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 17mn records with an `auto_increment` field. The structure is something like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Year1             |  Year2    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | 2001              | 2         |
| 2      | 2001              | 1         |
| 3      | 1999              | 3         |
| 4      | 2004              | 2         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I'd like to reorder the physical structure of the whole table by changing the `auto_increment` ID to match the `Year1` and `Year2` columns when ordered in ascending order. Something like this..

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Year1             |  Year2    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | 1999              | 3         |
| 2      | 2001              | 1         |
| 3      | 2001              | 2         |
| 4      | 2004              | 2         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Is this possible with a query in MySQL or should I use PHP and loops, et al.?

**Update**
The use case is this: The actual data I have is stored in a specific pattern. I wouldn't want the end user to identify the pattern (2001, then 2001, then 1999, etc).. Hence I'd like to rearrange the data in a standard, sorted fashion..

There are no foreign keys for this table.

Comment: Possible yes, but why should you want it? You can sort on `Year1` and have the same output.

Comment: don't, do it! this is not how to work with a database

Comment: what is your exact use case, because this doesn't sound like the right way fixing something

Comment: changing the auto-increment id is possibly a very bad idea depending on what this table is used for.  what is the problem you are trying to solve with this, we may be able to offer alternatives

Comment: Why don't you create a new table and re arrange records there. And use the new table where you require it. Is it possible for you? Then we have solution.

Comment: The actual data I have is stored in a specific pattern. I wouldn't want the end user to identify the pattern (2001, then 2001, then 1999, etc).. Hence I'd like to rearrange the data in a standard, sorted fashion..

Comment: @hims056: That option is open.. But how would I do that without carrying the existing "ID" fields there?

Comment: SELECT Year1,Year2 FROM table ORDER BY Year1 ASC;

Comment: @DavidHoude Thanks but looking to physically reorder the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all take a backup of your database

Instead of re arranging your actual table create a new table and insert values from the old one. like this:

Create table with auto increment, primary key

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`ID` int auto_increment primary key, `Year1` int, `Year2` int)
;
```

Insert with `SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO Table2
       (`Year1`, `Year2`)
SELECT Year1, Year2
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Year1, Year2;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0798f5/1)

Comment: Thanks for the code sample as well. Didn't know you could sort the query before inserting.

Comment: @Reddox: Beware, an insert of 17 million rows could kill your server; best to experiment first with a small subset of rows, to see how it will cope.

Comment: @vincebowdren +1 for that. A little too late though! I learnt not to try stuff on live/large data today!